# $_POST security for PHP Webservice

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, post

I apologize if this question has been asked before, if it has just link me to it in a comment.

So I've created a web-service for an android/iOS app with `php` that works like this.

1. The app sends a request to `http://www.example.com/ws/getCookingData.php` with 2 `$_POST` paramaters `userID` and `foodType`
2. The `php` file then queries the database using those two variables and returns a `json_encode` result.

My worry is that if someone were to discover my web-service link they could spam it with post requests resulting in 100's of call to my database that are just un-needed

Below is an example of my current `getData.php` file

```
<?php
$userID = mysql_escape_string($_POST['userID']);
$foodType = mysql_escape_string($_POST['foodType']);

$mysqli = getDB();

echo json_encode(getDate($mysqli, $userID, $foodType); //mysql database interaction is here

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

There is nothing here preventing hackers from attempting to post malicious SQL statements into my database

So what I'm wondering is if I added a 3rd parameter to my post request called `appID` would this be a good solution?

For example if I were to update my `getData.php` file to below would this be much more secure or is there a vulnerability I'm missing?

```
<?php
$appID = $_POST['appID'];

if($appID === "hardCodedEquivalentID"){
    $userID = mysql_escape_string($_POST['userID']);
    $foodType = mysql_escape_string($_POST['foodType']);

    $mysqli = getDB();

    echo json_encode(getDate($mysqli, $userID, $foodType); //mysql database interaction is here

    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

If this is a good solution or there is already an equivalent practice that would achieve what I'm trying to do please let me know

Comment: `"There is nothing here preventing hackers from attempting to post malicious SQL statements into my database"` - Not having a SQL injection vulnerability would be the answer to that.  We can't know for certain because we don't see your data access code, but given this code I find it likely that you do have such a vulnerability.  `"if I added a 3rd parameter to my post request called appID would this be a good solution?"` - Anybody using your application would see that value.  It wouldn't be a secret.

Comment: @David regarding your second point, how would anybody be able to see the appID value?

Comment: @CamConnor: By monitoring the traffic between the application and the service.  Unless you're encrypting that traffic within the application?

Comment: If I switched over to https would it be encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question

> My worry is that if someone were to discover my web-service link they
>   could spam it with post requests resulting in 100's of call to my
>   database that are just un-needed

If someone wants to DoS you then you can't do much in your code to prevent it but you may try using service like cloudflare. Not worth worrying about it at the beginning.

About

> There is nothing here preventing hackers from attempting to post
>   malicious SQL statements into my database

then just read documentation on [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` function which is deprecated. Secondly create a function which will authenticate the user and see whether the user has the permission to access the data. And thirdly try to `LIMIT` the data to 100 or so if possible.

Hardcoding the appId is not the solution. Create unique Id's for each specific registered user and then match that `appId` against that particular user. And when their session is expired clear the access token. And at the start of their session, you can login in them and create new access token and can use the same for their entire session.

Answer (score -3):

**1-** Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

**2-** Use `str_replace(" ","",$_POST['userID'])` and `str_replace("%20","",$_POST['userID'])`(Because malicious attacks involves in using %20 and space to inject sql query)

**3-** Add this line to the top of the page, so the script only takes request if its been from your website (That's what I am using too!)

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($referrer,"yourwebsite.com")) {
} else {
die();
}
```

Comment: All bad advice.  Blacklisting specific characters doesn't protect from SQL injection, *not executing user input as code* does.  And referrer headers are easily spoofed.

Comment: Of course not a full prevention, but will filter a lot of bad requests and helps the OP to make a better security. No need -1 though.

Comment: This advice doesn't help anybody "make a better security".  This code provides a *false* sense of security.  It hides security problems from the developer without hiding them from the attacker.  This is the *opposite* of security.  There is in every way a need for a -1 because this is a bad answer.